# How to get the path that threw an UnauthorizedAccessException?

Tags: c#, exception

Would anyone know if when you catch an UnauthorizedAccessException in C# its possible to access the path that threw it? I dont want the error message just the path that caused the problem. The try catch block I have could catch on a number of different ones but I need to report it it and continue on to the next directory/file without adding the entire exception message.

Comment: Possibly a key in the [Data property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception.data?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Exception_Data)? It's astounding that there isn't a documented API for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe make your error handling more granular so you are only catching a single attempt when it blows up? You could do this (without repeating yourself) by refactoring the offending code out to a utility method - i.e.

```
TryCopyFile(path1);
TryCopyFile(path2);
TryCopyFile(path3);
```

Where `TryCopyFile` catches the exception and logs the (single) path that was passed as an argument.

Comment: Took your advise on this and made the error handling more granular

Answer (score 1):

In the Message property of the UnauthorizedAccessException, you'll see something like this:

```
Access to the path 'E:\Domains\xxx\wwwroot\Images\main.aspx' is denied.
```

You can parse the path out of this Message.

Comment: This approach is likely to cause problems with portability, localization and possibly newer versions of the .net framework.

Comment: Yeah I considered doing this however I thought that since the exception message is static and its simply adding a variable to the message there might be some method of accessing that variable directly instead of parsing it so I figured I check first if that was possible.

Comment: It's a terrible API that makes you parse error messages.